# How to access boundfield values in a Gridview Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, controls, boundfield

I have a grid view control having some bound and template fields as follows

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" Visible="False" />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Question">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnques" runat="server" onclick="btnques_Click" 
Text='<%# bind("Question") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Now, what I want to do is that on the click event of a buttom `btnques`, I want to access its corressponding boundfield `ID`'s value and store it in a label. Can anyone tell me how to do this ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

should be like

```
 Text='<%# bind("Question") %> CommandArgument='<%# Eval("QuestionId") %>'
```

and then in code behind you can acess like...

```
protected void grd_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "")
    {
       e.CommandArgument // will return the id 
    }        
}
```